# Solaris: Increase TCP's Initial Congestion Window to 10 segments (tcp slow-start)

Tags: solaris, tcp, performance-tuning

How can the [Initial Congestion Window be increased to 10](http://www.google.com/research/pubs/pub36640.html)? It seems [it can be done with `TCP_INIT_CWND`](http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?messageID=456274), but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ndd to tweak the tcp parameters.  Get a list:

```
ndd /dev/tcp \?
```

The only one I see that looks similar is tcp_cwnd_max (I'm not well versed in the guts of TCP) and it's set to 1048576:

```
ndd /dev/tcp tcp_cwnd_max
```

You can also use ndd to change the parameters dynamically.  To make them stay changed after a reboot, add a set line in /etc/system

Comment: Max is not the same as initial so I don't think that is it. Perhaps I could add one that is not in the list. I will try later.

Answer (score 0):

The new features in [Solaris Express 1/06](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/SOLWHATSNEW/gbqhg.html) seems to suggest that an application can change this parameter and then points to the TCP(7P) man page which itself suggests it can be set by an application

```
 An appli cation can use this option to set  the  initial cwnd  
 to a specified  number of TCP segments. This applies to the cases
 when the connection first starts and restarts after an  idle
 period.
```

As this seems to be application related you may get a better answer on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/).